# DAX expression for ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY ORDER BY equivalent

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, row-number

I have a SQL statement like this:

```
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[market], [MEASURE_TYPE] 
                    ORDER BY AM, REP, ORDER_KEY)) AS ORDER_KEY
```

I want to write a DAX to implement the above SQL statement.

Comment: You need [RANKX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax) function.

Comment: Do you need this as a static column in a table, or a measure that calculates on the fly in response to the filter changes?

Comment: @KosukeSakai it should be a static column.

Comment: In general avoid RANKX it is an extremely expensive operations.

Answer (score 3):

This is not as simple in DAX as in SQL. Here is an example:

```
Order Key Within Partition = 
VAR CurrentMarket = [Market]
VAR CurrentMeasureType = [MeasureType]
VAR CurrentAM = [AM]
VAR CurrentREP = [REP]
VAR CurrentOrderKey = [OrderKey]

VAR CurrentPartition = FILTER (
    a, -- the table name
    [Market] = CurrentMarket
    && [MeasureType] = CurrentMeasureType
)

RETURN SUMX (
    CurrentPartition,
    IF (
        ISONORAFTER (
            CurrentAM, [AM], ASC,
            CurrentREP, [REP], ASC,
            CurrentOrderKey, [OrderKey], ASC
        ),
        1
    )
)
```

[image: Result]

**EDIT:** Power Query would be better to achieve this.

```
let
    /* Steps so far */
    Source = ...,
    ...
    a = ...,
    /* End of steps so far */

    /* Add steps below to add Order Key Within Partition column */
    Partitions = Table.Group(
        a,
        {"Market", "MeasureType"}, {"Partition", each _}
    )[Partition],
    AddedOrderKeys = List.Transform(
        Partitions,
        each Table.AddIndexColumn(
            Table.Sort(_, {"AM", "REP", "OrderKey"}),
            "Order Key Within Partition",
            1
        )
    ),
    Result = Table.Combine(AddedOrderKeys)
in
    Result
```

Comment: I tried to implement this, but after writing the code for new column, the screen is stuck in working on it for the last four hours. My table has almost 3 million records.

Comment: Too bad! Power Query based approach would be better in that case. I will update the answer.

Comment: The power query approach is great, elegant and fast! Thank you so much! Kudos to @Kosuke Sakai!

Answer (score 1):

I contribute with an alternative solution to the RANKX. The answer containing the Power Query is the correct one because avoid using calculated columns.

```
Sales[Sequence by Customer] = 

VAR CurrentDate = Sales[Date]

VAR CurrentTime = Sales[Time]

RETURN COUNTROWS (

    FILTER (

        CALCULATETABLE (

            Sales, 

            ALLEXCEPT ( Sales, Sales[Customer] )

        ),

        Sales[Date] < CurrentDate

          || ( Sales[Date] = CurrentDate 

               && Sales[Time] <= CurrentTime )

    )

)
```

[Source](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/numbering-sequence-of-events-in-dax/)